# how to silent print with FPDF and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, pdf, printing, fpdf

I have a script which creates letters as PDFs dynamically using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). I have been able to get the [AutoPrint function](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script36.php) working which brings up the print dialog on load.

There is another function on the previous link called AutoPrintToPrinter which is supposed to conditionally allow silent of loud printing.

```
function AutoPrintToPrinter($server, $printer, $dialog=false)
{
    //Print on a shared printer (requires at least Acrobat 6)
    $script = "var pp = getPrintParams();";
    if($dialog)
    $script .= "pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;";
else
    $script .= "pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.automatic;";
$script .= "pp.printerName = '\\\\\\\\".$server."\\\\".$printer."';";
$script .= "print(pp);";
$this->IncludeJS($script);
}
```

I know the printer and server name but nothing happens. Even if i ask for 'loud' printing, I don't even get the dialog box.

I've also looked at the [Adobe Tutorials](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.981.html) around the matter and have tried the following ammended code

```
var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.automatic;
pp.printerName = "Adobe PDF";
this.print(pp);
```

All with no luck.

Comment: are you hoping to print via the browser or the server?

Comment: That's what I thought. The answers so far have completely missed what you're trying to do. :-)

Comment: Confirm that `$server` and `$printer` do not contain any quotes or other characters that would break the generated Javascript code. Try outputting the generated script to the browser as plain text so you can check that it's valid. Finally, the example you're working from possibly assumes that it's being viewed using the Adobe PDF viewer; if your browser is using a different PDF viewer, then it may not have the same scripting capabilities or API as the Adobe viewer, so your script may not work there.

Comment: I am using Adobe PDF viewer, the server and printer variables do not contain any invalid characters,

and the code generated is...

var pp = this.getPrintParams();
pp.interactive = pp.constants.interactionLevel.full;pp.printerName = '\\\\oc-print-003v\\Claims';this.print(pp);

Comment: Hmm... I think I'm running out of ideas then. Sorry. But the key point here, I think, is that PHP and FPDF are not really very relevant to the problem. The question is really about the Javascript code required in your PDF to get Adobe PDF viewer to print automatically on load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically PHP cannot easily connect Hardwares.

You can user shell execute comment to print a file in php as follows

For windows server

```
shell_exec("'C:\Program Files\Adobe\Acrobat 6.0\Reader\acrord32.exe' /t c:\filename.pdf \\myserver\myprinter");
```

For linux server

```
exec("lp file.pdf");
```

I am not sure about this. Hope this will help you ... Try this.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work, I wonder if it's because they refer to an actual file whereas I'm creating my PDF on the fly